# Retarded (Advanced) GreenFunction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, greens-functions

I need to show that Green Function:

$\displaystyle G(\vec{r},t;\vec{r}^{\prime},t^{\prime}) = \frac{\delta(t-t^{\prime}\pm |\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{\prime}|\,/c)}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{\prime}|}$

Obeys

$\displaystyle \nabla^2 G -\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial t^2} = -4\pi \delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r}^{\prime})\delta(t-t^{\prime})$

I tried to use the identity for Laplacian :

$\displaystyle \nabla^2 (\psi\phi) = \phi\nabla^2\psi + \psi\nabla^2\phi + 2\vec{\nabla}\phi\cdot\vec{\nabla}\psi $

As follows:

[image: My work]

But I couldn't get nice results. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just solve the wave equation for the Green's function. And you can prove this way that the solution you have is indeed a solution of that equation. Or you must do like the way you stated above?

Comment: Yes. I need to put that Green function directly into wave equation.

Comment: I understand. Try what lionelbrits suggested and you should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is you are trying to take a derivative of the delta function.

You can do this inside an integral using a test function. Also, have you tried

$\delta(x) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\frac{1}{2\pi\epsilon} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\epsilon}}$

Also, don't drag around the $t'$ and $r'$, because $\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{d}{d(t-t')}$, so you are just slowing yourself down giving opportunity for mistakes to creep in. When you are done, just restore the $t'$ and $r'$.

Finally, note that

$\vec\nabla \delta(t-|x|) = -\delta'(t-|x|) \frac{\vec{x}}{|x|}$

$\nabla^2 \delta(t-|x|) = \delta''(t-|x|) -\delta'(t-|x|) \frac{2}{|x|}$

This should be sufficient.

Comment: They simplified my equations so nicely. But now I need to combine it with second term in the wave equation. It involves time derivative now. Should I use chain rule to combine them?

Comment: Well the time derivatives will just give $\delta''(t-|x|)$. They should just cancel out with what you got from $\nabla^2\delta$.

Comment: Ok but what is prime in your equations? I thought it is $\frac{d}{dx}$

Comment: Prime is just shorthand for the derivative of $\delta(z)$ wrt $z$. Since we apply the chain rule, the same derivative keeps popping up as an intermediate.